# Why the below piece of regular expression code is returning comma(,)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Please let me know why the following piece of code is giving the below result

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[!#$%&()*+-.]')
>>> pattern.findall("a,b")
[',']
```

There is no comma(,) symbol in re.compile method, but why it is matching comma also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[+-.]` is a single character in the range from `+` (ASCII 43) to `.`  (ASCII 46).

Between those two characters you find `,` (ASCII 44) and `-` (ASCII 45).

I guess you wanted `\-` instead of `-`.

Comment: Or, put the hyphen at the end of the range `[!#$%&()*+.-]`.